# How can I fix opentokrtc Got session undefined callback(new OpenTokSession(sessionid)) error

Tags: node.js

Using opentokrtc i get this message when I enter room name and try to join. Got session undefined callback(new OpenTokSession(sessionid)). I'm not able to load video.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did to get this working.

1. Clone the repo: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC
2. Get my API Key and Secret from http://TokBox.com
3. Replace OTKEY and OTSECRET with my corresponding key/secret in app.js
4. `npm install` to install the necessary packages
5. Run the app

Hope that helped!